# ldconfig -p(not ldconfig) equivalent command in Mac

Tags: macos, command, shared-libraries, lib, dyld

I want to list the dynamic libs and there paths available on the Mac OS 13. Like in linux we can do as:

```
ldconfig -p | grep ssl
libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
libssl.so.1.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```

And I want to select the latest ssl version like in this case it is libssl3.

How to do this on Mac 13.

update_dyld_shared_cache command doesn't have any options.
And the below dyld command doens'nt work.

```
`DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES /usr/bin/true`
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it my self. I used the following commands to use the latest one:

```
crypto_path=`brew list openssl | grep "libcrypto.dylib$"`
ln -s $crypto_path /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```